# Plotting bar chart on canvas in Python

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, plot, tkinter

I'm trying to plot a bar chart onto a Canvas widget using tkinter. Based from an example on 'how to plot a bar chart grouped by a column' that i found on the internet, this is the test program i used to plot the graph that i want:

```
df=pd.read_excel("testdata.xlsx")

x = 'Gender'
y = 'Sales'

a = df[[x, y]]
a = a.groupby(x).sum()
a.plot(kind='bar',legend=False)
plt.show()
```

The program should plot a bar graph grouped by the 'Gender' and plot the sum of 'Sale' for each gender like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sggX.png).

So i've tried to incoporate this code into my tkinter code, which looks something like this:

```
f = Figure()
myplot = f.add_subplot(111)
myplot = self.df[[x, y]]               #make a subset df of the columns to   be plotted
myplot = myplot.groupby(x).sum()       #groupby column 'x' and calculate sum
myplot.plot(kind='bar',legend=False)
self.Canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=self.top)  #self.top is the main window of the gui
self.Canvas1.get_tk_widget().place(relx=0.045, rely=0.545, relheight=0.4, relwidth=0.91)
```

I understand it's completely wrong and i'm assigning `myplot` to three different things. My question is how to write the correct code to create the same plot as the code above?

Comment: what is `self.top` ? Creat simp,e, working example so everyone could run it and test it.

Comment: why do you assign three different things to `myplot=` ? which one do you expect to get on screen ?

Comment: @furas so sorry that its confusing. I edited my question a bit, hope it makes more sense

Comment: can you add in question link to `how to plot a bar chart grouped by a column` and some simple data for dataframe so everyone could run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign to `myplot=` three different elements so I don't know what you try to plot.

Simple example how to plot `pandas` data in `tkinter` (using `matplotlib`)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

#
# http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html
#

# --- matplotlib ---
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use('TkAgg') # choose backend

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.pyplot import Figure

# --- other ---
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

# --- for example data --
import random
import math

# --- random data ---

df1 = pd.DataFrame([random.randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(60)])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([math.sin(math.radians(x*6)) for x in range(60)])

# --- GUI ---

root = tk.Tk()

# top frame for canvas and toolbar - which need `pack()` layout manager
top = tk.Frame(root)
top.pack()

# bottom frame for other widgets - which may use other layout manager 
bottom = tk.Frame(root)
bottom.pack()

# --- canvas and toolbar in top ---

# create figure
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.Figure()

# create matplotlib canvas using `fig` and assign to widget `top`
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, top)

# get canvas as tkinter widget and put in widget `top`
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

# create toolbar               
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, top)
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack()

# --- first plot ---

# create first place for plot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)

# draw on this plot
df1.plot(kind='bar', legend=False, ax=ax1)

# --- second plot ---

# create second place for plot
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)

# draw on this plot
df2.plot(kind='bar', legend=False, ax=ax2)

# --- other widgets in bottom ---

b = tk.Button(bottom, text='Exit', command=root.destroy)
b.pack()

# --- start ----

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Github: [furas/python-examples/tkinter/matplot-canvas/example-1](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/matplotlib-canvas/example-1)

---

**EDIT:** I created example data

```
data = {
    'Gender':['F', 'M', 'F','M'],
    'Sales': [1, 2, 3, 4],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x = 'Gender'
y = 'Sales'

new_df = df[[x, y]].groupby(x).sum()
```

and then I used this to display canvas.

```
# --- matplotlib ---
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use('TkAgg') # choose backend

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.pyplot import Figure

# --- other ---
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

# --- GUI ---

root = tk.Tk()

# top frame for canvas and toolbar - which need `pack()` layout manager
top = tk.Frame(root)
top.pack()

# bottom frame for other widgets - which may use other layout manager 
bottom = tk.Frame(root)
bottom.pack()

# --- canvas and toolbar in top ---

# create figure
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.Figure()

# create matplotlib canvas using `fig` and assign to widget `top`
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, top)

# get canvas as tkinter widget and put in widget `top`
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

# create toolbar               
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, top)
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack()

# --- plot ---

data = {
    'Gender':['F', 'M', 'F','M'],
    'Sales': [1, 2, 3, 4],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

x = 'Gender'
y = 'Sales'

new_df = df[[x, y]].groupby(x).sum()

# create first place for plot
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# draw on this plot
new_df.plot(kind='bar', legend=False, ax=ax)


# --- other widgets in bottom ---

b = tk.Button(bottom, text='Exit', command=root.destroy)
b.pack()

# --- start ----

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I managed to figure it out based on your example. All i needed was the `ax=myplot`, so i changed it to this:

   `test = self.df[[x, y]]               
   test = test.groupby(x).sum() 
   test.plot(kind='bar',legend=False, ax=myplot)`